# What is <div /> (without a child) used for?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

**Background**

I was checking material UI documentation (specifically, JS in Responsive drawer section). I found `<div className={classes.toolbar} />` in the code. I expected `<div className={...}>` always has at least one child element and all elements, including `<div>` itself and all children, are considered to be in the class. However, this does not have any child.

**Question**

What does `<div className={classes.toolbar} />` actually do?

Comment: It's just an empty div... it's the same as `<div className={classes.toolbar}></div>` but being empty you can shorthand it `<div className={classes.toolbar} />`

Comment: just look at the toolbar class in the styles def

Comment: is used to take some space in page

Answer (score -1):

Most probably it should serve as some kind of separator. For example, if you want to force two `<span />` elements to be on separate lines (they are inline elements) - just put another `<div />` in between. Ofcourse, css can make spans to behave as block level elements (`display: block`;), `<div />` is just for those who for some reason unknown doesn't want to use css.

#### Update

By checking example on the docs page here is what that class actually do:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .jss319 {
    min-height: 64px;
  }
}
```

It turns `div` into divider which push content of the drawer down.